# How do you install the decorator package from the Python package index in Windows?

Tags: python, module, package, pypi

I went into the python command line and typed $ easy_install decorator like how it says on the website https://pypi.python.org/pypi/decorator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're on Windows, so I will provide you with an extremely simple Windows-friendly way to install the Python package.

1. Obtain [`get-pip.py`](https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py) from pip-installer.org
2. Execute `get-pip.py` using whichever version of Python you have installed
3. Use the new `pip.exe` tool obtained in step 2 to install the `decorator` package

If you have Python 2.7 installed in `C:\Python27`, steps 2 and 3 will look like this:

1. `C:\Python27\python.exe get-pip.py`
2. `C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe install decorator`

I don't have a Windows machine running in front of me right now; so, let me know if my memory has failed me and the example commands I listed above do not work for you. Like mgilson pointed out in his answer, you need to execute these commands from a command prompt (run `cmd.exe` from the Start Menu).

For future reference, adding your Python installation path and its `Scripts` subdirectory to your system's `PATH` environment variable make operations like this a lot less cumbersome. You can do this using `setx` (e.g. `setx PATH "C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;%PATH%"`).

Answer (score 3):

`easy_install` is a *shell* command line tool.  Exit the python prompt and just type:

```
easy_install decorator
```

(the `$` is typically found in documentation to represent the shell's prompt).

If that doesn't work, you'll probably need to run it as root:  `sudo easy_install decorator`.<sup>1</sup>

<sup><sup>1</sup>I'm assuming that you're on a unix-like system.  If you're on windows, I can't help you ;-)</sup>

Comment: In CPython 2.x, CPython 3.x, and Jython, the Python prompt is ">>>". In Pypy, the Python prompt is ">>>>".

Comment: I got a syntax error on the decorator when i tried inputting it on shell. I'm on windows so i can't do the second option