# Import error: No module named 'scipy._lib'

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, pip, pythonanywhere

I'm using pythonanywere.com to deploy my Django application. So I've installed a few machine learning libraries to that virtual environment.

```
(venv) 19:16 ~ $ pip3 list
Package         Version           
--------------- ------------------
certifi         2018.4.16         
chardet         3.0.4             
DAWG-Python     0.7.2             
Django          2.0.5             
docopt          0.6.2             
idna            2.6               
numpy           1.14.3            
pip             10.0.1            
pymorphy2       0.8               
pymorphy2-dicts 2.4.393442.3710985
python-dateutil 2.7.3             
pytz            2018.4            
scikit-learn    0.19.1            
scipy           1.1.0             
setuptools      39.1.0            
six             1.11.0            
sklearn         0.0               
wheel           0.31.1
```

But when I tried to `python3 manage.py runserver` I got this

```
    from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
  File "/home/kirillkorolev/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py", line 134, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "/home/kirillkorolev/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 11, in <module>
    from scipy import sparse
  File "/home/kirillkorolev/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/__init__.py", line 110, in <module>
    from scipy._lib._version import NumpyVersion as _NumpyVersion
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy._lib'
```

Previously I did the same thing on a local machine and it worked fine.

Tested in a console on pythonanywere.com under Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

Comment: do you use `python manage.py`to run it?

Comment: That sounds like you've got a broken scipy install -- perhaps one of the packages you installed did a partial install?  If so, you might be able to fix it by reinstalling scipy.

Comment: @GilesThomas I couldn't really install it once again, because of disk quota. When I uninstalled and ran 'pip3 install scipy', all I got was 'Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 122] Disk quota exceeded'

Comment: Hmm, that sounds like it might have been the original problem, then -- perhaps it ran out of disk space while it was trying to install the first time around.   Your best solution is to get more disk space.

Comment: I have the same problem as you but I am far from being out of disk space. Did you find the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is just an update. I also faced same error. Solution of this issue is installation of below package.
`sudo apt install --reinstall python*-decorator`

Comment: Note that if you use zsh you need to escape the asterisk, so `sudo apt install --reinstall python\*-decorator`

Comment: What should Windows users do?

Comment: I am not using windows anymore, but I did some quick search and I found this link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21359261/how-do-you-install-the-decorator-package-from-the-python-package-index-in-window). Check here

Answer (score 7):

This seemed to resolve itself for me just by running:

```sh
 pip uninstall scipy &&  pip install scipy
```

Even though I had the latest version of scipy (1.4.1)

Comment: Executing "pip uninstall scipy" several times until there were no old packages left solved this issue for me, too.

Answer (score 0):

My issue has been `No module named 'scipy._lib._ccallback'`, it was solved by:

```
pip3 uninstall scipy==1.7.1
pip3 install scipy==1.4.1 --user
```